# Horizontally tile tables in listview?

Tags: asp.net, listview

I have records from database separated by department, I want to tile them horizontally inside different tables (for each department). Here is what I tried (This does not work)

Aspx

```
    <asp:ListView ID="lvUnderwriting" GroupItemCount="6" runat="server" GroupPlaceholderID="grpPlaceHolder1" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
       <LayoutTemplate>
     <table>
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="grpPlaceHolder1" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
     </table>
          </LayoutTemplate>
          <GroupTemplate>
                 <span><b><%# Eval("gensubbusiclass") %></b></span>
           <table>
                     <tr>
                            <th>Role Name:</th>
                            <th>Pending Tasks:</th>
                            <th>On Leave:</th>
                    </tr>    
                    <tr>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span> <%#Eval("RoleName") %></span></td>
                            <td><span><%# Eval("Count") %></span></td>
                            <td><span><%# Eval("OnLeave") %></span></td>
                       </tr>
                   </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Database rows
[image: Database rows]
My current results. For some reason the second department is divided into two tables. Also how do I tile them horizontally?
[image: Current Results]

Comment: [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SukeshMarla/nested-listview-in-Asp-Net/) might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay what I got was that ListView cannot display master detail records out of the box. Here is what I tried to get it working for me. The trick was to dynamically add a new row to the table if the header databound item was changed, the database records need to be sorted in advance to get this working. Referenced from here [using Asp.net 3.5 ListView 4 Guys from Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513210920/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx)

Aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvUnderwriting" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceHolder1">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="4px">
            <tr>
                <th>Role Name:</th>
                <th>Assigned:</th>
                <th>On Leave:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
            </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <%# AddGroupUnderwriting() %>
            <td><%# Eval("RoleName") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("Count") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("OnLeave") %></td>               
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

C#

```
// Add group row to underwriting grid
private string prevUWBusinessClass = "";
public string AddGroupUnderwriting()
{
    string currentUWBusinessClass = Eval("gensubbusiclass").ToString();
    if (currentUWBusinessClass != prevUWBusinessClass)
    {
        prevUWBusinessClass = currentUWBusinessClass;
        return string.Format(@"<tr><td colspan=""3""><h3>Department: {0}</h3></td></tr>", currentUWBusinessClass);
    }
    else
        return "";
}
```